# High performance Google Apps Script version?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am planning a Web app tightly integrated with the Google platform. Calendar, Drive, Docs, you name it.
My only concern is GAS processing time, as it is well known that script execution is slow. Testified.

I wonder if is there any professional grade version (paid?) that allows faster script execution...

Comment: This site is for questions about using web apps but this looks to be a question for Google customer / sales service. Please contact a Google sales representative. Also you could post your quetion on the Google Apps Script community -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community. By the other hand, you could reword the question but it should be in such way that it's about an specific problem like how to reduce the execution time of a representative code example of what you are planning to do.

Comment: By the other hand, you could reword the question but it should be in such way that it's about an web application end-user specific problem like how to reduce the execution time of a representative code example of what you are planning to do as end-user because developing web apps is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Hi @Rubén, under one perspective this is also a tech question, as I thought there could be a high-performance plan, with well-known tech-specs...

Comment: Hi Riccardo, I agree with @Rubén that this might be best directed to Google.  Our focus with GAS is more oriented toward its use in Google Sheets, so I don't know that we're in the best position to answer this.  In its current form, the question is really too broad to be answered by anyone but Google.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you get lucky, the best you can have is Early Access otherwise it will cost you $12+/month (**https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html**)

[image]

**https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas**

Comment: Customer is running G Suite for Education

Comment: @Riccardo in that case you already have the "highest" version

Comment: Problem is speed not execution limits

Comment: then the speed is a subject of programming level. if the script is badly written, the (execution) speed is reduced.

Comment: Thanks @user0, even a properly written script will not be so fast.